# Is there alternative for Java's ' byte[] decodeFile = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(fileBase64); ' in Python?

Tags: java, python

I am rewriting java code in python. The code works with different files through Spring. It opens such formats as JSON, DBF, RAR, XML and converts the data into String.
There is always a line in every code:

```
byte[] decodeFile = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(fileBase64); #(1)
```

Or in the block:

```
public interface FileService {

    String convert(String file, String fileName);

    @Service
    class FileServiceImpl implements FileService {

        @Override
        public String convert(String fileBase64, String fileName) {
            byte[] decodeFile = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(fileBase64);
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
                out.write(decodeFile);
                out.close();
                return convertToJson(new File(fileName));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Basically I do not understand the purpose of line (1).

So, the question is: should I do something like that in Python? If it is necessary, then: how can I do it in Python?

Thank you for any possible advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the following line

```
byte[] decodeFile = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(fileBase64); #(1)
```

The MIME encode/decoder generates Base64 encoded output/decoded values in MIME format.

You can use the quopri python module for similar things.
You can refer below the link.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html

You have to use the code like this

```
encodedValue = quopri.decodestring(<your encoded>, True)
```